# SPOT 6 parameters to open data in matlab

Tags: remote-sensing, matlab

I'm trying to open SPOT 6 data on Matlab using multibandread, but since I don't have some of the paremeters I'm only getting a black image.
I've been looking on the web for these parameters but I haven't found anything, not even in the User guide from Astrium. I have a tiff image.

The parameters I need are:

- interleave (bip/ bil/ bsq)
- Data type
- byte order (le/be)
- offset, xstart, ystart